Will select query get executed if it written in SP or Package declaration?
Create or Replace package SamplePackage
As
Cursor cur is select * from abc;
refCurParam as ref cursor return cur%rowtype;
Begin
End SamplePackage;
The above package used in SP in order to  define type of a parameter used in sp

I don't understand the question. Maybe it would be clearer if code you posted compiled, but it is invalid. Try to post valid example and describe what you meant to say with code you post.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you are asking how to make a strongly-typed ref-cursor then:
CREATE PACKAGE SamplePackage AS
  CURSOR cur IS SELECT * FROM abc;
  TYPE refCurParam IS REF CURSOR RETURN cur%ROWTYPE;
END SamplePackage;
/

Then if you want to use the cursor then:
DECLARE
  v_abc SamplePackage.cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN SamplePackage.cur;
  LOOP
    FETCH SamplePackage.cur INTO v_abc;
    EXIT WHEN SamplePackage.cur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_abc.a || ', ' || v_abc.b || ', ' || v_abc.c );
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE SamplePackage.cur;
END;
/

Which requires you to OPEN the cursor before using it.

Or, more simply, if you don't want the cursor you can use the underlying table's ROWTYPE:
CREATE PACKAGE SamplePackage
AS
  TYPE RefCurParam IS REF CURSOR RETURN ABC%ROWTYPE;
END;
/

fiddle
